# JWT(Json Web Token) farm servers implementation

Tags: .net-core, jwt, server-farm

I am working in a solution, where we have a farm server in order to handle the application.
Is there a problem if I use JWT ? I mean if my server A is down and the user got the token from server A and send the request to server B using the JWT generated by the server B, the server B will able to authenticate the request using the JWT generated by the server A?

best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the tokens should be accepted if the **audience** ("aud") is valid.

> The "aud" (audience) claim identifies the recipients that the JWT is
> intended for. Each principal intended to process the JWT MUST
> identify itself with a value in the audience claim. If the principal
> processing the claim does not identify itself with a value in the
> "aud" claim when this claim is present, then the JWT MUST be
> rejected. In the general case, the "aud" value is an array of case-
> sensitive strings, each containing a StringOrURI value.  In the
> special case when the JWT has one audience, the "aud" value MAY be a
> single case-sensitive string containing a StringOrURI value. The
> interpretation of audience values is generally application specific.

B could also check that the token's **issuer** ("iss") is one of the farm servers, or all the servers could use the same issuer.

More info in the [JWT spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519).